# Converting SQL query into DAX query

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

I want to convert the below SQL query into a PowerBI DAX query.

lead ([effective start date])
over (partition by [PF#] order by [effective start date] ) as next_date

Thanks in advance.

I tried the EARLIER function, but it didn't work.